# Conditional PDF and CDF problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a problem below:

**The probability density function (PDF) of the random variable X is**

$$
f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
1-|x| &\text{|x| < 1}\\
0&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

a. Find and sketch the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of X.

b. Calculate the probability that |x| ≥ 1/2.

c. Calculate the conditional probability density function 
$$
f_{X||X|≥1/2} (x||X|≥1/2)
$$

d. Calculate the conditional cumulative distribution function (CDF), and sketch it.
$$
F_{X||X|≥1/2} (x│|X|≥1/2)=P(X<x ||X|≥1/2)
$$

I can solve a. and b. P(|x| ≥ 1/2) = 1/4. But for c. and d., I confused because of the condition term (|X|≥1/2) and do not know how to solve it. In the textbook, there is a formula:
$$
f_{X|X≤a}(x|x≤a) = \begin{cases}
f_{X}(x)/F_{X}(a) &\text{x ≤ a}\\
0&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

In conditional CDF and PDF, I always confused between ≤  and ≥. How can I understand it correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\mathbb P\left(X\leq x||X|\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)
=\frac{\mathbb P\left(X\leq x ,|X|\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\mathbb P\left(|X|\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)}
=\frac{\mathbb P\left(X\leq x ,X\geq \frac{1}{2},X\leq -\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\mathbb P\left(|X|\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)}$

It is enough calculate $\mathbb P\left(X\leq x ,X\geq \frac{1}{2},X\leq -\frac{1}{2}\right)$.
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb P\left(X\leq x ,X\geq \frac{1}{2},X\leq -\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &   x < -1 \\
 \int_{-1}^xf(x) dx & -1 \leq x < -\frac{1}{2} \\
 \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}}f(x) dx & -\frac{1}{2} \leq x < \frac{1}{2} \\
 \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}}f(x) dx
+  \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}f(x) dx& \frac{1}{2}\leq x < 1 \\
1 & x\geq 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}